# Firebase Authentication results in Error Code "auth/network-request-failed"

Tags: authentication, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-redux

I'm developing a react-native app which uses Firebase for authentication.

When ever I'm starting the authenticate request it results in the following error:

```
N {code: "auth/network-request-failed", message: "A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred."}
```

Here is the code I use to authenticate/create user. Note: I'm using redux to maintain state.

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(user => authenticateUserSuccess(dispatch, user))
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
            firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .then(user => authenticateUserSuccess(dispatch, user))
                .catch(() => authenticateUserFail(dispatch));
        });
```

Following are the dependencies I'm using in the project:

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "firebase": "^3.7.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "react": "15.4.2",
    "react-native": "0.42.0",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^3.38.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.3",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
}
```

Comment: I had exactly the same issue .in my case it was because my country has been put in OFAClist so it was boycotted by Google .I closed emulator ,ran my Proxy and I got done !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your phone/device. make sure the google service is running. just open playstore to check it. if it's not running, restart your device and check again. if it's running then do your sign in/create user firebase again. I solve my problem with this way

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, everything worked fine, I use React Native Debugger. I didn't remember that for some tests I enabled the "**Enable Network Inspect**" option. From there I started getting the error, the solution, just was disable the option. The post was a long time ago, but the last day happened to me, and maybe it's good for someone today.